# How to apply a filter to only one column? The columns differ by a value of the same binary filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have visualizations that have bar graphs set up in 6 separate sheets. These bar graphs need to go side by side for comparison. 2 graphs will be combined to form one side-by-side graph. They only differ by a filter that is set to either 0 or 1 in the corresponding sheets. Everything else is the same.

Example: 
In sheet 1, XMJ is filtered by Misdemeanor = 0
In sheet 2, XMJ is filtered by Misdemeanor = 1

I'd like to make them show side-by-side for comparison.

I have already tried duplicating XMJ and bringing it side-by-side but couldn't apply Misdemeanor = 1 or 0 separately to the duplicate column.

Here is the file: [Visualz](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hQdlQzAZQQ-tK5Bd277jyn-X_NjCJ0Jp)

Comment: Can you save the file as a [packaged export](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/save_savework_packagedworkbooks.htm).  The file as-is has no data in it.  It should have a .twbx extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a [table calc filter](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/filtering-view-without-filtering-underlying-data).

Create a calculation `lookup(min([Misdemeanor]),0)` and put it on your filter shelf in each sheet and you can filter them independently.

Table calcs happen after the data is displayed on the viz (see [Order of Operations](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm)).

The `min([Misdemeanor])` part tells Tableau you want to look at the minimum value (this could be also max/attr/sum it wouldn't matter in your case).

The `lookup(measure,0)` tells Tableau to look at the current row of the measure (but again, after the data is already on the table).  At this point, you can filter it independently.

EDIT: Another thought is you might just have the filters set to All Using this Datasource or (multiple) selected sheets.  You can change this behavior in either the worksheet (1st picture) or dashboard (2nd worksheet).

[image: Worksheet filter]
[image]